# How to change interval for kubectl top?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I like to know how I can change the time interval of `kubectl top` for monitoring pods. At the moment it updates very slowly (I think it is more than 15s) and I want to have a more up to date values for the resource usage of my pods.

I am aware that I can use some other tools such as grafana, prometheus, etc. But when I work in terminal I like to have some simple monitoring tool running at the same environment.

Comment: Hi, you can use `watch -n2 kubectl top pods` to do that. here interval value is 2 seconds

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it doesn't work. The `watch -n` just defines the interval for the watch and not the `kubectl top` which means `watch` constantly checks for an update but `kubectl` just gives it the old data. I tested this by scaling pods and even with `-n 1` I could see the new pods after around 15s. The situation is completely different with `kubectl get pods` and this commands just feed the `watch` correct and live information.

Comment: hmm alright, I do not see any flags for making a request in interval, `kubectl top pods --help` . perhaps it could be a good Enchantement for the k8s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no flag for [kubectl top](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5a7b978c7401efad5672bcc876bcf5d3dfa71bd0/pkg/kubectl/cmd/top/top_pod.go#L42-L55) for setting the refresh rate since it depends on the information collected by Heapster and Heapster depends on the [kubelet metrics scraping interval](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kubernetes-users/D-xsnFtmeAk/_KvfvjJHAQAJ).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Then this is not suitable for me since based on the link: "it should be at least 2X bigger than scraping interval on kubelet which currently is 15s" and 30s is too much for me and I prefer to just check GUI.